# Splash screen not showing in Phonegap Build app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am building an app with Phonegap Build and I started with this as the base:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start

I've replaced all the default graphics with app specific ones (icons, splash screens) but when I build the app, the splash screen is always black.

Comment: Which device Android? iOS?

Comment: Both. It doesn't show up for any devices.

Comment: Ok, can you please confirm image resolution matches with resolutions mentioned in `config.xml` file? Also, name ;)

Comment: Also, check the last solution from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184367/blank-splash-screen-on-android-with-phonegap-build

Comment: @jeekonline I edited the images files "as is" and jjust replaced them with my own images so I assume they are the correct names and resolutions. But I will double check taht the config is the same as the file names.